# In what sense "the wicked are ransom for the righteous" Proverb 21:18?

Tags: mishlei, kaparah-atonement

> `WEB` [Prov 21:18](https://www.stepbible.org/?q=version=NETfull%7Cversion=NASB2020%7Cversion=ESV%7Cversion=THOT%7Creference=Num.8.17%20Prov.21.18&options=VNGUVH&display=INTERLEAVED)  The wicked is a ransom for the righteous; the treacherous for the upright.
> כֹּ֣פֶר»[shall be] a ransom לַצַּדִּ֣יק»for the righteous רָשָׁ֑ע»The wicked וְתַ֖חַת»the place יְשָׁרִ֣ים»for the upright בּוֹגֵֽד׃»and the transgressor
>
> Numb 8:17   For all the first-born among the children of Israel are mine, both man and beast: on the day that I smote all the first-born in the land of Egypt I sanctified them for myself.

If the Proverb is considered as a ransom in technical sense then it would sound like the following Islamic Hadith, which I suspect was copied from some corresponding Jewish teachings.

> Sahih Muslim book 37 [Chapter 8](https://www.iium.edu.my/deed/hadith/muslim/037_smt.html) : THROWING OF NON-BELIEVERS IN HELL-FIRE FOR BELIEVERS AS DIVINE GRACE AND MERCY
>
> Book 37, Number 6665: Abu Musa' reported that Allah's Messenger (may peace be upon him) said: When it will be the Day of Resurrection Allah would deliver to every Muslim a Jew or a Christian and say: That is your rescue from
> Hell-Fire.
>
> Book 37, Number 6666: Abu Burda reported on the authority of his father that Allah's Apostle (may peace be upon him) said: No Muslim would die but Allah would admit in his stead a Jew or a Christian in Hell-Fire. 'Umar b. Abd al-'Aziz took an oath: By One besides Whom there is no god but He, thrice that his father had narrated that to him from Allah's Messenger (may peace be upon him).

I think the reference to the ransom is merely a proverbial judgment which sometimes happens to the wicked who incur God's wrath, especially for persecuting the righteous. It is of course not a means for ransom or redemption, but how have this verse or similar concepts have been interpreted?

Comment: Rashi writes, "A righteous man is rescued, and a wicked man comes in his stead (above 11:8), such as Mordecai and Haman."